# Newbee questions: I better ask all that before I install... will it work on my Notebook and with my printers?

Tags: release-juno

**Folks, 
before I start installing this new OS and stumble upon predictable questions, here is my setup and my previous problems.**

My computer is a [Lenovo Thinkpad W520](https://support.lenovo.com/hr/en/solutions/pd015362), a powerhouse with an i7-2720, 32 GB RAM, two fairly big SSDs, fingerprint reader, USB3, eSata and a color calibration tool - you name it, this was built for photo and video editing.

The printers are a Samsung M288 printer/scanner and a Brother MFC 6490CW2.

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18 LTS and ran into several problems - the machine did not boot properly, sound did not work and more, printer installation felt like a dentist appointment, Wifi was dead slow, Bluetooth did not work and a few more. I could fix some of that but it was no fun at all. So, I am ready to quit, and as a long-time Mac user without enough money for Apple gear I feel attracted by elementary...

**As elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, too, do I have to expect the same problems?

Did any of you ever successfully install this OS on a similar machine?
**

Comment: PS: intended use.

1. Video editing with Shotcut
2. Audio editing 
3. Photo editing 
4. organization of media files
5. Standard tasks like web browsing, writing letters, spreadsheets etc.
6. Maybe, maybe use Wine or similar to work with the construction software SketchUp  or Vectorworks plus a renderer or so.

Comment: hi there, I do not have experience using a mashine like yours but based on my experience and what I read from other users - eOS has resoved a lot of problems other ubuntu distributions cannot. Also, stackExchange is a question and answer community but no a support forum. Asking a question - you receive answers not only for you but for everyone with the same issue - that's why asking a lot of questions in one and the same post is not recommended. Also - for a lot of your questions there are already answers here - I recommend you to use the search box first and then ask every question separately

Answer (score 0):

Since Elementary OS 5.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I would suspect you would have similar issues, if not exactly the same.
There are other flavors of Ubuntu that you might want to consider trying that are on a newer code-base.
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
You should be able to use 19.04 or 19.10 if so inclined.
Maybe check out ["Ubuntu Studio"](https://ubuntustudio.org/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Works great my T420, if that is any help.

1. Samsung and Brother.  Go to their site and see if they have drivers for Linux.  My Brother MFC-J6720DW has drivers so I am good.  You must look at the messages in the terminal to see if there are any unmet dependencies.  These can usually be found using Synaptic.  While you're at it add system-config-printer as well.  This is a far superior printer configuration utility and has a GUI but must be launched from the command line.
2. Fingerprint reader.  I don't have one but this could be problematic.

Regardless.  First time you experiment just do the standard installation on a spare drive and don't try anything fancy like dual boot.